# httpd failed to start

Tags: linux, centos, apache-httpd

**I got this problem when I renewed my SSL certificate.**
**Output is below:**

```
 httpd.service - The Apache HTTP Server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/httpd.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
  Drop-In: /etc/systemd/system/httpd.service.d
           └─quick_kill.conf
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2019-10-08 14:39:37 PST; 21min ago
     Docs: man:httpd(8)
           man:apachectl(8)
  Process: 3343 ExecStop=/bin/kill -WINCH ${MAINPID} (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
  Process: 2862 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/httpd $OPTIONS -DFOREGROUND (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 2862 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Oct 08 14:39:35 .noblecomms.net.ph systemd[1]: Starting The Apache HTTP Server...
Oct 08 14:39:37 .noblecomms.net.ph systemd[1]: httpd.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Oct 08 14:39:37 .noblecomms.net.ph kill[3343]: kill: cannot find process ""
Oct 08 14:39:37 .noblecomms.net.ph systemd[1]: httpd.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
Oct 08 14:39:37 .noblecomms.net.ph systemd[1]: Failed to start The Apache HTTP Server.
Oct 08 14:39:37 .noblecomms.net.ph systemd[1]: Unit httpd.service entered failed state.
Oct 08 14:39:37 .noblecomms.net.ph systemd[1]: httpd.service failed.
```

**Ports 443 and 80 are open, httpd service just won't start.**

**ps -ef | grep httpd outputs:**

```
mostrev+ 19108 5796 0 13:09 pts/0 00:00:00 grep --color=auto httpd
```

---

**/etc/systemd/system/httpd.service.d/quick_kill.conf output**

```
[Service]
TimeoutStopSec=5
```

---

**netstat output**:

```
Active Internet connections (w/o servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State      
tcp        0      0 localhost:52986         localhost:websm         ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 xxxx.xxxx.:56252 10.1.1.2:microsoft-ds   ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 localhost:9981          localhost:60868         ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 xxxx.xxxx.:57862 10.1.1.2:49153          ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 xxxx.xxxx.n:3322 host-b8e2d970.nob:34712 ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 localhost:50862         localhost:6379          TIME_WAIT  
tcp        0      0 localhost:51096         localhost:6379          ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 localhost:6379          localhost:51096         ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 localhost:9981          localhost:60870         ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 localhost:46384         localhost:6378          ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 localhost:60868         localhost:9981          ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 xxxx.xxxx.:46770 10.1.1.2:ldap           ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 xxxx.xxxx.n:3322 250.37.61.113.acc:51962 ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 localhost:60870         localhost:9981          ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 xxxx.xxxx.:38050 10.1.1.2:msft-gc        ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 localhost:46386         localhost:6378          ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 xxxx.xxxx.:56254 10.1.1.2:microsoft-ds   ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 xxxx.xxxx.:56256 10.1.1.2:microsoft-ds   ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 localhost:6378          localhost:46384         ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 localhost:6378          localhost:46386         ESTABLISHED
tcp6       0      0 localhost:websm         localhost:52986         ESTABLISHED
Active UNIX domain sockets (w/o servers)
Proto RefCnt Flags       Type       State         I-Node   Path
unix  2      [ ]         DGRAM                    26584    /var/lib/samba/private/msg.sock/3120
unix  2      [ ]         DGRAM                    32058    /var/lib/samba/private/msg.sock/3121
unix  3      [ ]         DGRAM                    14346    /run/systemd/notify
unix  2      [ ]         DGRAM                    14348    /run/systemd/cgroups-agent
unix  2      [ ]         DGRAM                    26586    /var/lib/samba/private/msg.sock/3122
unix  2      [ ]         DGRAM                    27284    /var/lib/samba/private/msg.sock/3126
unix  6      [ ]         DGRAM                    14369    /run/systemd/journal/socket
unix  30     [ ]         DGRAM                    14371    /dev/log
unix  2      [ ]         DGRAM                    27762    /var/lib/samba/private/msg.sock/2382
unix  2      [ ]         DGRAM                    32027    /var/lib/samba/private/msg.sock/2886
unix  2      [ ]         DGRAM                    23660    /var/run/chrony/chronyd.sock
unix  2      [ ]         DGRAM                    27285    /var/lib/samba/private/msg.sock/3127
unix  2      [ ]         DGRAM                    10147    /run/systemd/shutdownd
unix  2      [ ]         DGRAM                    33498    /var/lib/samba/private/msg.sock/4040
unix  2      [ ]         DGRAM                    27975    /var/lib/samba/private/msg.sock/3112
unix  2      [ ]         DGRAM                    32056    /var/lib/samba/private/msg.sock/3113
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     32773    
unix  2      [ ]         DGRAM                    23581    
unix  2      [ ]         DGRAM                    43016    
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     33139    
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     20791    
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     25665    /run/systemd/journal/stdout
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     33142    
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     24683    /run/dbus/system_bus_socket
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     57666    
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     33141    
unix  2      [ ]         DGRAM                    22401    
unix  2      [ ]         DGRAM                    58573    
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     33144    
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     14168    /run/systemd/journal/stdout
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     33116    
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     67352    
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     14152    /run/systemd/journal/stdout
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     23649    
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     21220    
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     17802    
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     33145    
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     33148    
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     21221    
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     33115    
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     20421    /var/lib/sss/pipes/private/sbus-monitor
unix  2      [ ]         DGRAM                    28024    
unix  2      [ ]         DGRAM                    29930    
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     26788    /run/systemd/journal/stdout
unix  2      [ ]         DGRAM                    36026    
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     33147    
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     21222    
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     1725     /run/systemd/journal/stdout
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     66005    
unix  2      [ ]         DGRAM                    19926    
unix  2      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     58582    
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     33150    
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     22383    
unix  2      [ ]         DGRAM                    33078    
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     28080    
unix  2      [ ]         DGRAM                    26799    
unix  2      [ ]         DGRAM                    32320    
unix  2      [ ]         DGRAM                    27800    
unix  2      [ ]         DGRAM                    28052    
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     20428    /run/dbus/system_bus_socket
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     27205    /run/systemd/journal/stdout
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     23595    /run/gssproxy.sock
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     33151    
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     20041    
unix  2      [ ]         DGRAM                    26623    
unix  2      [ ]         DGRAM                    13668    
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     33154    
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     29931    
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     33121    
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     33153    
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     22029    
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     26594    
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     23588    
unix  2      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     43025    
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     33124    
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     20783    
unix  2      [ ]         DGRAM                    1735     
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     33119    
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     26589    
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     33123    
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     14237    /run/systemd/journal/stdout
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     26625    
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     33126    
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     32047    
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     14147    /run/systemd/journal/stdout
unix  2      [ ]         DGRAM                    27961    
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     27281    /var/lib/sss/pipes/private/sbus-monitor
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     29917    
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     26057    /run/systemd/journal/stdout
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     27174    
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     26593    
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     33127    
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     22402    
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     19765    /run/dbus/system_bus_socket
unix  3      [ ]         DGRAM                    25418    
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     31045    /run/systemd/journal/stdout
unix  2      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     30535    
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     33130    
unix  2      [ ]         DGRAM                    20792    
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     34825    
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     59608    private/anvil
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     33129    
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     26787    
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     33132    
unix  2      [ ]         DGRAM                    21800    
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     19763    
unix  2      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     35787    
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     28079    
unix  2      [ ]         DGRAM                    26814    
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     65320    /var/lib/sss/pipes/nss
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     28600    
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     33118    
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     28021    /run/systemd/journal/stdout
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     26592    
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     21802    
unix  2      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     28606    
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     32946    
unix  2      [ ]         DGRAM                    67354    
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     33133    
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     32048    
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     30600    /run/dbus/system_bus_socket
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     19764    
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     63251    /run/systemd/journal/stdout
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     33136    
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     28601    /run/systemd/journal/stdout
unix  2      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     32329    
unix  2      [ ]         DGRAM                    27818    
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     33135    
unix  2      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     28603    
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     26591    
unix  2      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     51781    
unix  2      [ ]         DGRAM                    57644    
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     33138    
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     21801    
unix  2      [ ]         DGRAM                    19814    
unix  3      [ ]         DGRAM                    25419    
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     22403    /run/dbus/system_bus_socket
unix  2      [ ]         DGRAM                    26588    
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     32316    
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     33171    
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     26315    /run/systemd/journal/stdout
unix  2      [ ]         DGRAM                    30543    
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     1733     /run/systemd/journal/stdout
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     32294    
unix  2      [ ]         DGRAM                    32071    
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     29068    
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     25786    
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     20422    /var/lib/sss/pipes/private/sbus-dp_xxxx.xxxx.xxxx.3123
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     32091    
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     29081    
unix  2      [ ]         DGRAM                    42709    
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     27544    
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     29932    
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     33172    
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     28001    /var/lib/sss/pipes/private/sbus-monitor
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     33175    
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     29085    
unix  2      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     34455    
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     69745    /var/lib/sss/pipes/nss
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     33174    
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     62445    
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     32308    
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     14243    /run/systemd/journal/stdout
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     24936    
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     33177    
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     12973    
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     42713    
unix  2      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     27552    
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     32296    
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     32092    
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     22252    /run/systemd/journal/stdout
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     68374    
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     29087    
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     26305    
unix  2      [ ]         DGRAM                    42646    
unix  2      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     33426    
unix  2      [ ]         DGRAM                    25349    
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     33178    
unix  2      [ ]         DGRAM                    29075    
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     65281    /var/lib/sss/pipes/nss
unix  2      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     42710    
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     19120    
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     25054    
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     33181    
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     29086    
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     25951    
unix  2      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     34168    
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     32065    
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     33180    
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     32309    
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     14241    /run/systemd/journal/stdout
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     26169    /run/systemd/journal/stdout
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     42650    
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     14239    /run/systemd/journal/stdout
unix  2      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     33189    
unix  2      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     44657    
unix  2      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     42647    
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     26306    /run/dbus/system_bus_socket
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     42651    
unix  2      [ ]         DGRAM                    33898    
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     18988    
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     26699    /run/systemd/journal/stdout
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     32311    
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     19048    
unix  3      [ ]         DGRAM                    8689     
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     33156    
unix  2      [ ]         DGRAM                    32040    
unix  2      [ ]         DGRAM                    23764    
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     34065    
unix  3      [ ]         DGRAM                    8688     
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     33157    
unix  2      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     33429    
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     42714    
unix  2      [ ]         DGRAM                    32090    
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     33160    
unix  2      [ ]         DGRAM                    57126    
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     32315    
unix  2      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     32060    
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     33159    
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     29082    
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     32302    
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     25667    /run/systemd/journal/stdout
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     33162    
unix  2      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     33428    
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     34064    
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     32312    
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     32066    
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     20427    /var/lib/sss/pipes/private/sbus-dp_xxxx.xxxx.xxxx.xxxx.3123
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     33163    
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     22475    
unix  2      [ ]         DGRAM                    39182    
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     26693    /run/systemd/journal/stdout
unix  2      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     30323    
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     32293    
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     33165    
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     14272    /run/systemd/journal/stdout
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     26168    
unix  2      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     32450    
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     32303    
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     29084    
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     32297    
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     29083    
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     33120    
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     27543    
unix  2      [ ]         DGRAM                    30314    
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     29267    /run/systemd/journal/stdout
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     33166    
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     33169    
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     30019    
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     33168    
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     29080    
unix  2      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     29506
```

---

**quick_kill.conf** output:

```
[Service]
TimeoutStopSec=5
```

**tail -f /var/log/httpd/error_log** output:

```
[Thu Oct 10 09:39:01.757405 2019] [suexec:notice] [pid 21293] AH01232: suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/sbin/suexec)
[Thu Oct 10 09:39:01.758608 2019] [ssl:emerg] [pid 21293] AH02311: Fatal error initialising mod_ssl, exiting. See /etc/httpd/logs/ssl_error_log for more information
[Thu Oct 10 09:42:22.747752 2019] [suexec:notice] [pid 3021] AH01232: suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/sbin/suexec)
[Thu Oct 10 09:42:22.790473 2019] [ssl:emerg] [pid 3021] AH02311: Fatal error initialising mod_ssl, exiting. See /etc/httpd/logs/ssl_error_log for more information
[Thu Oct 10 10:02:30.774432 2019] [suexec:notice] [pid 11196] AH01232: suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/sbin/suexec)
[Thu Oct 10 10:02:30.775639 2019] [ssl:emerg] [pid 11196] AH02311: Fatal error initialising mod_ssl, exiting. See /etc/httpd/logs/ssl_error_log for more information
[Thu Oct 10 11:05:32.920750 2019] [suexec:notice] [pid 18791] AH01232: suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/sbin/suexec)
[Thu Oct 10 11:05:32.933032 2019] [ssl:emerg] [pid 18791] AH02311: Fatal error initialising mod_ssl, exiting. See /etc/httpd/logs/ssl_error_log for more information
[Thu Oct 10 11:09:07.092589 2019] [suexec:notice] [pid 2910] AH01232: suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/sbin/suexec)
[Thu Oct 10 11:09:07.154310 2019] [ssl:emerg] [pid 2910] AH02311: Fatal error initialising mod_ssl, exiting. See /etc/httpd/logs/ssl_error_log for more information
```

Comment: and? We cannot guess what was done to Apache.

Comment: Relevant recent output from `journalctl -u apache2` into your question, please.

Comment: it will spit the text from above

Comment: port 443 at 80 are closed, I cant start them

Comment: Ouput of `ps -ef | grep httpd` into your question too, please.

Comment: And `netstat -nap | grep -E ':(22|80|443)\b.*LISTEN'` (for now)

Comment: Take a look at `/var/log/httpd/error.log` and/or other files in the same directory. Are there any messages written there when you make an attempt to start `httpd`? Also, there apparently is a systemd drop-in file `/etc/systemd/system/httpd.service.d/quick_kill.conf`: what is in there?

Comment: I've updated the body of this post for reference

Comment: And the `netstat` output please...?

Comment: the output of netstat is now on the body of this post

Comment: What is in `quick_kill.conf`?

Comment: @AlexP Post is updated for reference

Comment: Add the contents of `/var/log/httpd/error_log` to your question. Run `tail -f /var/log/httpd/error_log` while starting the service from another terminal to see what is happening when you attempt to start it.

Comment: @NasirRiley I've updated the post for reference.

Comment: The error_log you just posted says: `See /etc/httpd/logs/ssl_error_log for more information` **Do that.**

Comment: You still haven't provided the `netstat` output [I asked for](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/545652/httpd-failed-to-start#comment1012300_545652).

Comment: use this command for netstat `sudo netstat -plunt | egrep ":80|:443"`

Comment: well, we decided to give up on that one and focus on data recovery

Comment: thanks to everyone who exert their effort on this one

Answer (score 0):

If apache/httpd was working before you installed the new SSL, I strongly suggest that you review the syntax of your configuration by using

```
httpd -t
```

Any time you edit the configuration of apache/httpd you want to ensure that the syntax is correct otherwise when you restart the apache/httpd service won't come back up. Here is an example of a working SSL setup.

```
<VirtualHost *:443>

DocumentRoot "/var/www/jesus"
ServerName jare.site
ServerAlias www.jare.site

ReWriteEngine on

SSLEngine on
SSLProtocol all -SSLv2 -SSLv3
SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.jare.site/cert.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.jare.site/privkey.pem
SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.jare.site/fullchain.pem

</VirtualHost>
```

Now, I have edited  the SSLCertifacateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.jare.site/cert.pe by removing the "m" from the end and as you can see, it has cause apache/httpd not to come back up.

```
<VirtualHost *:443>

DocumentRoot "/var/www/jesus"
ServerName jare.site
ServerAlias www.jare.site
#AllowOverride All
#Require all granted
ReWriteEngine on
SSLEngine on
SSLProtocol all -SSLv2 -SSLv3
SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.jare.site/cert.pe <---
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.jare.site/privkey.pem
SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.jare.site/fullchain.pem

</VirtualHost>
```

Testing httpd syntax.

```
$ httpd -t
AH00526: Syntax error on line 25 of /etc/httpd/conf.d/jesus.conf:
SSLCertificateFile: file '/etc/letsencrypt/live/www.jare.site/cert.pe' does not exist 
or is empty
```

httpd/apache refusing to start

```
$ service httpd restart
Redirecting to /bin/systemctl restart httpd.service
Job for httpd.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See 
"systemctl status httpd.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

Comment: ill try this thank you